# Background gif position transition to other ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, background, gif

So the problem is: i have a gif background that was set through a method of extension created by this guy [SwiftGif Link](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif)

I use method backgroundAnimated.loadGif(name: "giphy") to load current gif and it parses gif onto images then fills it onto arrays with consequent call of animatedImage method of UIImage class.
But the thing is - i want to preserve a state of looping gif when transiting to next ViewController through segue.
For example if i have bird flying over the centre of the screen and then randomly someone presses a button to go to next ViewController, gif resets and begins from the beginning. Help me to find a solution please

I thought of solutions:

- Pass coordinates of frame onto other ViewController through prepareForSegue
  Problem is - myBackground.frame is always at zero coordinates , so i have no idea how to get the frame it was stopped on last
- Start with CGRect initial frame position 
  Problem is - its not possible to guess position of frame it has stopped when transition button is pressed.
- Make one gif background for all ViewControllers (Have no idea how to implement such thing whatsoever)

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that your myBackground UIImageView is changing frame. I don't think so.

I guess its your gif is changing its key frame. So you need to store the index of the stopped key frame and start your gif from the key frame instead.

Comment: The complication is that a gif is divided onto images and put into array with delays and stuff, so that it could be passed onto UIView.animatedImage method which animates a sequence of parsed image into array and I don't know how to start from that image animatedImage has processed last. I will be grateful if you have any ideas

Comment: I guess the underlying gif implementation is base on CAAnimation by looking at this wiki https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/wiki/Extended-use .So I think you can use the CALayer `timeOffset` to set the start from pervious stopped timeOffset. Detail about `timeOffset`: http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/